# ECO A80 Dutch Defense game for Analysis

Tags: analysis, dutch-defense

Embedded game was the one which I'd played some months back. As part of analysis, if this steps could get commented,- `1.d4 f5 2.Nf3 d5 3.e3 a5 4.Be2 h5` it will be better for a newbie to pick it up & play well. It gives good picture for one to have some diff. in opening principle.

Queen Loss for Black is blundered & clumsy move which Black had played `12.* Qxg6`. I hope its not kind of `Swindle`. If it is not what it could named as.

And if this blundered move `28.cxd5` not happened, then white would've not lost its Queen. Will it be positive for White to have win or still Black is better in a streak to win.

After 13th move does white had played any other blundered moves, which is after my side Queen's end. What white would've done something precautions as pawns were upfront on castling side.

> Particularly comment rather not considering blunders which I had
>   mentioned, as the game maybe progressed considering better defense. Is
>   I am right, else its not better played rather?

Here is fen for the game,

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2017.08.03"]
[White "kingggggggggggggg"]
[Black "bram-stokers"]
[WhiteElo "855"]
[BlackElo "1172"]
[TimeControl "600"]
[ECO "A80"]
[Termination "bram-stokers won by checkmate"]
[Result "0-1"]
[CurrentPosition "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/3P4/8/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq d3 0 1"]

1.d4 f5 2.Nf3 d5 3.e3 a5 4.Be2 h5 5.O-O e6 6.c3 g5 7.Qc2 Nc6 8.Bd3 g4 9.Ng5 Qxg5 10.e4 f4 11.e5 f3 12.Bg6+ Qxg6 13.Qxg6+ Ke7 14.Qg5+ Kd7 15.Qf5 Be7 16.Qc2 h4 17.Na3 h3 18.gxh3 gxh3 19.Qd3 Nh6 20.Qxf3 Rg8+ 21.Kh1 Nf5 22.Qxh3 Nd8 23.b3 Nf7 24.c4 dxc4 25.bxc4 a4 26.d5 exd5 27.Qxf5+ Ke8 28.cxd5 Bxf5 29.Rg1 Be4+ 30.f3 Bxf3+ 31.Rg2 Rxg2 32.Nc4 Rg8#  0-1
```

Comment: This game is beginner level chess. 3...a5 followed by 4...h5 completely ignores the basic opening principles. Both players' tactical vision is so extremely limited that they do not realize that they're hanging pieces all over the place. I would suggest that you try to find every single time where one side either drops a piece in one move, or misses to capture a hanging piece, and post your findings. I think you could learn a lot from doing just that instead of being told by stronger players of all the mistakes in this game.

Comment: I didn't told we are stronger players, maybe our name implies. Let that be simple game. Thanks for pointing. What if Black Queen got cut step esrlier, maybe felt that perspective you are. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: I don't think this question is unclear. We provide feedback on beginner games. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Bad_Bishop I suspect some of the issues with it being unclear are the poor English, this person's history and their apparent lack of improvement, among other minor things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some broad strokes, mostly tactical, I think there were some more inaccuracies on a positional level:

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2017.08.03"]
[White "kingggggggggggggg"]
[Black "bram-stokers"]
[WhiteElo "855"]
[BlackElo "1172"]
[TimeControl "600"]
[ECO "A80"]
[Termination "bram-stokers won by checkmate"]
[Result "0-1"]

1.d4 f5 2.Nf3 d5?! {Slightly weakens Black's pawn structure.} 3.e3 a5?! {Weakens pawn structure some more, and is a waste of time. Black should start developing his pieces.} 4.Be2 h5?! {Same as 3...a5.} 5.O-O e6 6.c3?! {d4 is not threatened, why defend it? The c-pawn should instead attack Black's centre by c4, maybe after Nbd2.} g5 {Looks menacing, but isn't. Black still has not developed a single piece so far!} 7.Qc2 Nc6 {Finally, some development. In move 7...} 8.Bd3?! {Moves an already developed piece instead of continuing to develop the queenside, and with no clear objective. The bishop doesn't actually do anything important on d3. If anything, it should go to b5 to assist a future Ne5.} g4 9.Ng5? {Drops a piece for no reason. Better: Ne5.} Qxg5 10.e4 f4 11.e5 f3?? {Drops the queen. Better: Develop the g8 knight to join the attack.} 12.Bg6+? {Misses Bxg5, drops the bishop instead.} Qxg6 13.Qxg6+ Ke7? {Allows Bg5+ with tempo. Better: Kd7.} 14.Qg5+? {Misses Bg5+.} Kd7 15.Qf5?? {Drops the queen. Better: gxf3, followed by Qf4 or Qg3.} Be7?? {Misses exf5.} 16.Qc2? {Relieves all pressure on the black king for no reason. Better: Qf7.} h4 17.Na3 h3 18.gxh3 gxh3 19.Qd3?! {Too passive. The queen should go to g5 to keep the black rook off of the now open g-file.} Nh6 20.Qxf3 Rg8+ 21.Kh1 Nf5 22.Qxh3 Nd8 23.b3 Nf7 24.c4 dxc4 25.bxc4 a4 26.d5 exd5? {Drops a piece. Better: Kd8 or Kd8, to break the pin while the bishop on c8 will defend e6.} 27.Qxf5+ Ke8 28.cxd5?? {Drops the queen. Better: e6.} Bxf5 29.Rg1?? {Allows the following mate. Better: Nb5, threatening Nxc7+.} Be4+ 30.f3 Bxf3+ 31.Rg2 Rxg2 32.Nc4 Rg8#  0-1
```

To recap:

- Black handled the opening very poorly. Instead of developing, he pushed pawns for 6 entire moves. In the end, he wins because he blundered a little less (but still a lot!)
- White started developing (good), but in a way that was very passive. The c3-Qc2-Bd3 plan did not make a lot of sense, it attacked a protected pawn instead of the actual holes in Black's structure, like e5.
- Remarkably, both players to manage to blunder away their queens with the opponent failing to spot this.
- White fails to use the advantage he had after taking the black queen, instead he drops his queen again and subsequently loses.

My advice for both players: **Train tactics and avoid blunders!**

For White specifically: **Don't just wait for your opponent to generate pressure, strike while he is still weak!**

For Black specifially: **Don't just rush your pawns, develop you pieces to assist an attack!**

Answer (score 2):

Lets forget the game is a Dutch as you leave opening theory extremely quickly with amateur moves.  I recommend you learn basic principals which are available for free in many places such as this Susan Polgar video: https://youtu.be/U9cIr7P9gkg

Answer (score 0):

My advice for white is in the comments to the FEN below:

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2017.08.03"]
[White "kingggggggggggggg"]
[Black "bram-stokers"]
[WhiteElo "855"]
[BlackElo "1172"]
[TimeControl "600"]
[ECO "A80"]
[Termination "bram-stokers won by checkmate"]
[Result "0-1"]
[CurrentPosition "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/3P4/8/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq d3 0 1"]

1.d4 f5 2.Nf3 d5 3.e3 a5 4.Be2 (4.c4 {This threatens to win a centre pawn for a flank pawn. If Black plays 4...dxc4 then 5. Bxc4is an efficient developing move. Also, c3 is now an even better square for the knight.}) h5 5.O-O e6 6.c3 g5 7.Qc2 Nc6 8.Bd3 g4 9.Ng5 (9.Nfd2 {9.Ng5 drops a piece}) Qxg5 10.e4 f4 11.e5 (11.exd5 exd5 12.Re1+ {Closing the centre makes black's game simpler, which is bad when you are behind in material.}) f3 12.Bg6+ Qxg6 13.Qxg6+ Ke7 14.Qg5+ (14.Bg5+ {Brings another attacker in.}) Kd7 15.Qf5 {I don't know why you hang your queen here.} Be7 16.Qc2 h4 17.Na3 h3 18.gxh3 (18.g3 {This blocks up the kingside, meaning that no attack can proceed.}) gxh3 19.Qd3 Nh6 20.Qxf3 Rg8+ 21.Kh1 Nf5 22.Qxh3 (22.Rg1 {Trading down when up material makes more sense, as it diffuses black's attack. The h3 pawn will fall soon enough.}) Nd8 23.b3 {I don't know what this move aims to achieve.} Nf7 24.c4 dxc4 25.bxc4 a4 26.d5 exd5 27.Qxf5+ Ke8 28.cxd5?? Bxf5 29.Rg1 Be4+ 30.f3 Bxf3+ 31.Rg2 Rxg2 32.Nc4 Rg8#  0-1
```

Comment: If White needs any advice, then 12.Bxg5 **must** be one of them.